# Datepicker in Wordpress own theme

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I am trying to implement the datepicker in my own theme in Wordpress (Version 4.3.1). Unfortunately without success. I think one problem is, that I have a SSL certificate.

My functions.php

```
function datep_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', array( 'jquery' ) );

  wp_register_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css' ); 

  wp_register_style('jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery-ui.css');
  wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );   
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'datep_scripts' );
```

My page.php

```
<input type='text' name="event_date" id="EventDate" class="form-control input-lg"/>
....
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //show calendar windows
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#EventDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'dd.mm.yy'
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

I always get the error message:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Does anybody have the same problem?

Greets, yab86

Comment: Thank you Rohit. I added my code above.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery library is not loaded at the time this code is executed.  Make sure you load the jQuery library before you write any jQuery code.

You could fix this by loading jQuery in the `<head>` above any other javascript.